# User export in Excel broken in Moodle

Tags: php, excel, moodle

My Moodle user reports (generated by bulk user actions) are broken. When I download an Excel file of a list of users, the file I get is riddled with wrongly encoded data.

For example:

[image: Screenshot of the worksheet]

A little further in the file, it does show some data as you can see, but this is absolutely not easy to read, nor acceptable to offer to my client.

I've already checked the headers this report sends, and those are normal (application/vnd.ms-excel).
This is on version 2.0.3 of Moodle.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Moodle are you on?

Comment: 2.0.3. Apologies, forgot to add. Will edit that in.

Comment: The odd thing is, I can't get this to work _at all_ on my install. The page just reloads but I don't get any file. There are a few bugs in the tracker around this functionality but I can't find anything that resembles either my or your problem!

Comment: Yes, I've looked around and there are plenty of issues concerning Excel exports, but not what I'm getting. It's very annoying because my client urgently needs this data. CSV's work, but that's not an option.

Comment: Can you not just load the CSV into excel and save it as an XLS from there?

Comment: @kevtufc I don't see why that would be necessary. This is a core function of Moodle and both me and my client expect it to work. I appreciate the suggestion, but I really want the Excel export to simply work, as it's supposed to.

Comment: Accepted, of course. And I wouldn't have suggested that as a permanent answer but I was simply offering a temporary workaround since you mentioned that the data was required urgently.

Comment: You're right. Excuse me, I didn't mean to be short. It's true that they can use it as a temporary fix. I do however really want this fixed. I've noticed that the documents created (both .csv and .xls) have an empty line at the top, so I figure that has something to do with the headers being sent. Looking into that, I'll post again if I find something.

Comment: Even I had faced the same problem. Albeit not with the bulk export, but student's submitted assignments as spreadsheets. Although I am not associated with the project anymore, I still havent found a reliable solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen before when the language code (encoding set) is not configured or is left as default value.

To resolve this, dip into your `config.php` file and insert your language code like so:

```
$CFG->lang="language code here";
```

If you do this and it still doesn't work, you can check if there's a PHP error causing this by taking the following steps:

1. Turn on debug mode
2. download (any) excel export (but don't open it in Excel)
3. Right-click and open with notepad (or any text editor) and look at the first line - is there a PHP error printed? If so, this error will tell you where the issue is.

Hope that helps.